# Characters won’t store in the list

Tags: java, arrays, list

```
List<String> commandList = new ArrayList<String>();
int num = 0;
String command;

command = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter your commands here: ");

while (command.length() > num) {
    commandList.add(num, command.substring(num, num+1));
    num++;
}
```

I have the user input a String and I want to store each individual characters from the string into the list.

What I have right now doesn't do that correctly. How can I solve this?

Comment: Does it even compile? `myList.add()` takes only one argument...

Comment: [It's an overloaded method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add\(int,_E\))

Comment: @Mattrition Ah ok, you're right, my fault. Never used it yet though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do the following things

```
String [] myarray = command.split("");
List<String> commandList = Arrays.asList(myarray);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `charAt()` like this:

```
List<Character> commandList = new ArrayList<Character>();
for(int i = 0; i < command.length(); i++) {
    commandList.add(command.charAt(i));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
char[] charArray = command.toCharArray();
Character[] charObjectArray = ArrayUtils.toObject(charArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem to be incorrect.

I ran your code and all was all right...you have the normal and working code...